# Lm across many columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many numerical columns, The first col need to be regressed against the second column, then store the Rsqr value, then the first column against the thrid column , then stores the Rsqr value...and so on. Do this until the nth column has been regressed to the 1st column.

Id like the result to be a dataframe that houses the Rsqr values for colnames regressed.

ie

```
tested              rqr
col1 v col2         0.56
col1 v col3         0.28
col1 v col4         0.38
```

I know I havn't supplied data - i'm looking for the approach. I had been using a lm function called within a forloop to do this, but it takes very long. I'm wondering if theres an apply solution to this.

paul

Comment: Always supply data. At least, it earns you brownie points.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want R², you don't need to fit linear models, but can simply calculate Pearson's correlation coefficient. This will give you the correlation between all combinations of columns:

```
cor(yourDataFrame)^2
```

And this is an example for correlations with the first column:

```
set.seed(42)
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol = 4)) 
cor(df, df[,1])^2
#          [,1]
#V1 1.000000000
#V2 0.006508638
#V3 0.110714099
#V4 0.006231468
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a `dplyr` approach. The philosophy is to combine column names to create a formula for each regression you want to implement.

```
library(dplyr)

dt = data.frame(mtcars)

# specify columns to regress
y_col = "disp"
x_col = c("mpg","cyl","hp")

expand.grid(y=y_col, x=x_col, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(formula = paste(y,"~",x)) %>%
  group_by(formula) %>%
  mutate(r_sq = summary(lm(formula, data=dt))$r.squared) %>%
  ungroup()


#       y     x    formula      r_sq
#   (chr) (chr)      (chr)     (dbl)
# 1  disp   mpg disp ~ mpg 0.7183433
# 2  disp   cyl disp ~ cyl 0.8136633
# 3  disp    hp  disp ~ hp 0.6255997
```

Comment: @Roland 's comment is very useful as it will make things faster in case you have lots of data. Based on what you asked though, I'll focus on performing multiple regressions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using some typical `dplyr/purrr/tidyr/broom` idioms:

load the libraries:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(broom)
```

Here's the data:

```
dt = mtcars # already a dataframe
```

Here's the sequence to compute separate linear regressions for the columns `mpg`, `cyl`, and `hp` against the column `disp`, and get the r-squared for each regression:

```
dt %>% 
  select(disp, mpg, cyl, hp) %>% 
  gather(key = group, 
         value = measurement,
         -disp) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  mutate(model = map(data, ~lm(disp ~ measurement, data = .))) %>% 
  unnest(model %>% map(glance))
```

Here's the output:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 14]

  group            data   model r.squared adj.r.squared    sigma
  (chr)           (chr)   (chr)     (dbl)         (dbl)    (dbl)
1   mpg <tbl_df [32,2]> <S3:lm> 0.7183433     0.7089548 66.86320
2   cyl <tbl_df [32,2]> <S3:lm> 0.8136633     0.8074521 54.38465
3    hp <tbl_df [32,2]> <S3:lm> 0.6255997     0.6131197 77.08950
Variables not shown: statistic (dbl), p.value (dbl), df (int), logLik
  (dbl), AIC (dbl), BIC (dbl), deviance (dbl), df.residual (int)
```

To narrate the sequence in plain English:

- we take the dataframe, then
- convert from wide to long format to make a grouping column, then
- make a nested dataframe with one row per group, then
- compute a linear model for each group, then
- extract the output of the models, including the r-squareds, into a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set.seed(1)
df<-as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),10)) # reproducible data
paste0('col1 vs col',2:10)->column1 # first column : the regression
sapply(2:10,function(x){summary(lm(df[,1]~df[,x]))$r.squared})->column2 # the rsquared
final<-data.frame('reg'=column1,'rsquared'=column2) # the final data.frame

        final
            reg   rsquared
1  col1 vs col2 0.14190543
2  col1 vs col3 0.51242469
3  col1 vs col4 0.05973700
4  col1 vs col5 0.05149017
5  col1 vs col6 0.37621382
6  col1 vs col7 0.14208468
7  col1 vs col8 0.38533983
8  col1 vs col9 0.26596917
9 col1 vs col10 0.01758616
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to say taht some nas might appear in any of the columns - can they be removed as part of the apply call..? I don't want to remove the nas before i begin because i could loose many rows...only the nas between the 2 columns being tested.

Comment: @PaulBeales:check this link for `NA` and `lm` : http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-does-r-handle-missing-values-in-lm

Comment: by default they are omitted in the `lm` call

Comment: getting this error when i run the sapply line.                                                             Error in summary.lm(lm(df[, 1] ~ df[, x])) : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

Comment: then please put `dput(df)`. having the data helps a lot. And you can just write `summary()` instead of `summary.lm()`

Comment: @PaulBeales: also you got to adjust the `2:10` to the actual number of column you have.

Answer (score 0):

Taking large pointers from @etienne's soln, `data.table` answer below.

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100),10))
dt = setDT(df)
melt(dt, id.vars = "V1")[!is.na(value) & !is.na(V1),  # rm NAs
                         summary(lm(V1~value))$r.squared,  # lm call
                         variable]  # for each column

   variable         V1
1:       V2 0.14190543
2:       V3 0.51242469
3:       V4 0.05973700
4:       V5 0.05149017
5:       V6 0.37621382
6:       V7 0.14208468
7:       V8 0.38533983
8:       V9 0.26596917
9:      V10 0.01758616
```